# Fetching code from SVN

Tags: asp.net, svn, cruisecontrol.net

I am using cruise control .net for fetching code from SVN for an application.
I want to fetch it on the basis of change sets ,

below is the scenario for what i need.

If one team is working on build 1 and second team is working on build 2 and they are committing their code on SVN regularly.
Now i want to fetch code only of build 1, not of build 2.
How can i get it using cruise controls .net?

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! It helps if you're more specific, and tell us what you've tried and considered so far, and where you got stuck. Show us some code / config, etc.

Comment: are you talking about two different branches?

Comment: here is the code of my ccnet.config...where i am entering revision number
 
<tasks>
        <nant>
        <executable>D:\nant-0.92-bin\nant-0.92\bin\nant.exe</executable>
        <buildFile>D:\NANT_SCRIPTS\build.xml</buildFile>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>120</buildTimeoutSeconds>
        <buildArgs>-D:Rev=$[Revision]</buildArgs>
      </nant>
    </tasks>and below is the code of fetching code from nant on basis of revision number <exec commandline="checkout https://testproject.repositoryhosting.com/svn/test/Mockups/Test@${Rev}  D:\MyTest  --username test --password dp" />

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that CC.net can do it, but you can achieve it with NAnt manually using Subversion command line

Comment: Hi..Dima...how can we achieve using nant? I am also using nant.

Comment: You can take a look on Subversion command line (http://www.tigris.org/nonav/scdocs/ddUsingSVN_command-line.html.en) and use it via NAnt's <exec/> task (http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/exec.html).
Or maybe it will be easier for you to use separate repos for each build.

Comment: Hi..here is the code of my ccnet.config...where i am entering revision number <tasks> <nant> <executable>D:\nant-0.92-bin\nant-0.92\bin\nant.exe</executable> <buildFile>D:\NANT_SCRIPTS\build.xml</buildFile> <buildTimeoutSeconds>120</buildTimeoutSeconds> <buildArgs>-D:Rev=$[Revision]</buildArgs> </nant> </tasks>and below is the code of fetching code from nant on basis of revision number <exec commandline="checkout testproject.repositoryhosting.com/svn/test/Mockups/Test@${Rev} D:\MyTest --username test --password dp" />

Comment: can you please tell me about Changesets and revision in SVN? Because i want to get the code on the basis of changesets.Read my question one more time.

Comment: Dima..can you please look on to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513169/how-to-get-partial-update-from-subversion