# how to get partial update from subversion

Tags: svn, nant, revision

I'm in the following scenario in my application's repository:

- revision 7 (2 changed files, 1 added file)
- revision 6 (4 changed files)
- revision 5 (2 added, 2 deleted, 2 changed)
- revision 4 (3 changed files)
- revision 3 (12 added, 2 changed files)

I want to get a working copy that includes all changes from revision 3 to Head but does NOT include the changes for revisions 5 and 6.

I am using SVN merge for this, but changes are not being reflected, and I'm getting file conflicts for revision 5 and 6.

Below is the config file description of nant that contains executable commands for this.

```
<exec program="C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe" commandline="checkout https://test.repositoryhosting.com/svn/1_test@${Rev} D:\MyTest --username test --password 123"/> 
<exec program="C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe" commandline="merge -c  -6  https://test.repositoryhosting.com/svn/1_test  D:\MyTest  --username test --password 123"  />
<exec program="C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe" commandline="merge –c  -5  https://test.repositoryhosting.com/svn/1_test  D:\MyTest  --username test --password 123"  />
<exec program="D:\NANT_SCRIPTS\Delete Publish.bat"  commandline="${Rev}" />
<exec program="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe" commandline="-nologo -v / -p D:\ MyTest -u D:\PublishOutput_${Rev}" />
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What's your intention? Are you going to simply revert the changes done in the revisions 5 and 6?

Comment: Yes, i want to exclude the changes of revision 5 and 6 in my working copy, but need changes of revision 3,4,7 in working copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this the other way around:

- revert the changes of revision 6
- commit
- revert the changes of revision 5
- commit
- check out the Head revision

This should bring the working copy to the state you'd like. The changes of revision 5 and 6 will be reverted in the repository, but this will anyway happen when you commit your changes.

Comment: i want to make these changes in local working copy,I do not want to make changes in repository. So can i revert these from local working copy where i am fetching updates from SVN ?

Comment: It sounds weird... Why do you need all these actions in working copy if you're not going to commit those?

Comment: I will publish this working copy(D:\MyTest given in the commands above, this is location where i am fetching code)  code to create build. Is this make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure... Anyway, if the changes of revision 7 don't intersect with revision 5 or 6, you can try the following: 1) generate an SVN patch between revision 7 and 6; 2) check out revision 4 to a working copy; 3) apply a patch generated above and try to build this